# How to import a function in Next.js only on client side?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, client-side

I am very new to Next.js, so pardon me for my mistakes. I have this function written using in axios that I only want to run on client side, since it used localstorage. Dynamic imports only work for components. Is there a way I could do that for just a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing the data fetching on the client side. You can execute this code in `useEffect` which will won't be executed until after the component is mounted.

For example for client side fetch:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const doMyAxiosCall = async () => {
        ...

        // Set localStorage values here
   }

   // This will only be executed on the client
   doMyAxiosCall();
}, [])
```